# add 0.17 value to database in condition Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on django-form project with some customer detail, all things are good condition work properly but a value of tax 0.17 is not added in tax column, tax column still show NULL value in database and all other value added successfully, I use checkbox in tax field in my html form

I want if `taxamount == ['0.17']` a value 0.17 is added in tax column else 0 added in tax column with other value (print function is just use to check that my condition is working or not but condition work properly)

models.py

```
class CustomerDetail(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Ship_No = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Cell_qty = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    Cell_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    thimble = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    thimble_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    tax = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    DatePur = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

view.py

```
def addcustomer_view(request):
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        taxamount = request.POST.getlist('taxamount')
        if taxamount == ['0.17']:
            print('Tax added to database')
            CustomerDetail.tax = 0.17
        else:
            print('Tax not added to database')
            CustomerDetail.tax = 0
        
        form.save()

    return render(request, "customer.html")
```

**or is there any other way if checkbox is checked add 0.17 value to database otherwise add 0 to database in tax column**

Comment: you add to an instance  that it is not created CustomerDetail is not instantiated  instead  use  form.instance.tax = your value  and then form.save()  also in your function pass  only request  whre is the form instance ?

Comment: thanks @DimitrisKougioumtzis for your help now my form working properly and my bad to add form instance in view.py here otherwise I use form instance in my view function. thanks again